# ASP.NET Core data validation not showing in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a model `Event` with a ViewModel, Controller and View.

In this case it is about the CreateView

#### Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Verbonding.Models
{
    public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime EventStart { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventEnd { get; set; }

        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }    
        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Verbonding.Models.EventViewModels
{
    public class CreateViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string HouseNr { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventEndDate { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

#### Controller

I removed the actions that are not required for this question.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Verbonding.Data;
using Verbonding.Models;
using Verbonding.Services;
using Verbonding.Models.EventViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace Verbonding.Controllers
{
    public class EventsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private IEventData _eventData;
        private IOrganizationData _organizationData;
        private IAddressData _addressData;
        private ICategoryData _categoryData;
        private ICountryData _countryData;

        public EventsController(IEventData eventData,
            IOrganizationData organizationData,
            IAddressData addressData,
            ICategoryData categoryData,
            ICountryData countryData)
        {
            _eventData = eventData;
            _organizationData = organizationData;
            _addressData = addressData;
            _categoryData = categoryData;
            _countryData = countryData;
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();

            var categories = _categoryData.GetChildCategories();
            model.Categories = new List<Category>(categories);

            return View(model);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Category category = _categoryData.Get(model.CategoryId.GetValueOrDefault());
                Country country = _countryData.Get(1);

                _eventData.Add(model.Name, category, model.Description, model.LocationName, model.Street, 
                    model.HouseNr, model.PostalCode, model.City, country, model.EventStartDate, model.EventEndDate);
                _eventData.Commit();

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                var categories = _categoryData.GetChildCategories();
                model.Categories = new List<Category>(categories);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

#### View

```
@model Verbonding.Models.EventViewModels.CreateViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <h4>Algemene gegevens</h4>
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"))" class="form-control">
                    <option>Please select a Category</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Description" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <h4>Adresgegevens Evenement Evenement</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LocationName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="LocationName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LocationName" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Street" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div><input asp-for="Street" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; float: left"/></div>
                <div><input asp-for="HouseNr" class="form-control" style="width: 60px; float: left; margin-left: 20px" /></div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Street" class="text-danger" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseNr" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PostalCode" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="PostalCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PostalCode" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="City" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <h4>Tijden Evenement</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EventStartDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="EventStartDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EventStartDate" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EventEndDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="EventEndDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EventEndDate" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Now when I test this, the page does reload, and the fields that have been entered stay there, but there are no validation errors.

What can I do to get the validation errors on the page?

### Update

I found out that the properties of the `DateTime` type are required by default,
so I have changed these.

In the model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}")]
public DateTime EventStart { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}")]
public DateTime? EventEnd { get; set; }
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public DateTime EventStartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EventEndDate { get; set; }
```

This seems to have the desired effect for these fields.

### Update 2

Based on the comments from Dai I have updated the Model and ViewModel.
To test it out I started with the Name property and left the rest as it is.

In the Model:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In the ViewModel:

```
[required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

At first this did not have the desired effect. (But also no errors)

Then I changed `required` to `Required` with a capital `R`, and that did the trick.
I also needed to add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`, but that was nicely handled by Visual Studio.

Comment: Your ViewModel doesn't have any validation attributes, yet your model class does. I think you have them the wrong way around.

Comment: i.e. to my knowledge, Entity Framework does not recognize `[RequiredAttribute]` - yet ASP.NET MVC does. So move those attributes away from your business/domain entity objects and onto your ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

try to create file _ViewImports.chtml into your Views folder. Then add following lines to the file:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```